# package not found for ros tutorials

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

whenever I run the line

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-ros-tutorials
```

(i use melodic)

it gives

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-ros-tutorials
```

what can i do to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382278/package-not-found-for-ros-tutorials/) by [aavila17](https://answers.ros.org/users/77596/aavila17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-12**:
Ros requires a few setup steps on your part. Have you added the ros package repository to the `apt` config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at this web page: http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0